# Problem posting image to clipboard using Python and PHP

Tags: python, php

Hi everybody (my first post). Please be gentle!
I am running Windows 10 Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363.
Python 3.8.5
Apache 2.4.41

I found an example of how to copy an image to Windows clipboard.
If I run the program at cmd.exe level, it works and I'm able to paste the copied image from the clipboard.
If I execute the same program from within a PHP script (which is a requirement) using exec(program to run),it runs without any errors.
However the image is not in the clipboard.
I've tried creating a .bat file and then using PHP exec(.bat file), nothing is copied to the clipboard.
Again the .bat file when run at cmd.exe level, runs successfully.
I've run whoami at cmd.exe level and the correct user (ie myself as administrator) displays noellaptop\rorke
Besides using a .bat file, I've also tried exec(with the path to python and the python script to run).
Any suggestions or help will be appreciated as I'm not an experienced Python programmer.

The code below is the **Python script**.

```
#!c:/users/rorke/appdata/local/programs/python/python38/python.exe
 
from io import BytesIO
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image
import cgi, cgitb 
 
print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
 
# Create instance of FieldStorage 
#form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
#filepath = form.getvalue('image_url')
filepath = "C:/wamp64/www/PhotoApp2.0/favicon.ico"
#print(filepath)
 
def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    print("Done!")
 
image = Image.open(filepath)
output = BytesIO()
image.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
data = output.getvalue()[14:]
output.close()
 
send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
```

The code below is the **Php script**.

```
<?php
    $bat_filename = "aaCopyImage.bat";
    $bat_log_filename = "aaCopyImage_bat.log";
    $bat_file = fopen($bat_filename, "w");
    if($bat_file) {
        fwrite($bat_file, "@echo off"."\n");
        fwrite($bat_file, "echo Starting process >> ".$bat_log_filename."\n");
        fwrite($bat_file, "C:/Users/rorke/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/wamp64/www/cgi-bin/hpCopyText.py >> ".$bat_log_filename."\n");
        fwrite($bat_file, "echo End proces >> ".$bat_log_filename."\n");
        fwrite($bat_file, "EXIT"."\n");
        fclose($bat_file);
    }
    exec("aaCopyImage.bat");
?>
```

Comment: As it's a bit unclear - can you elaborate as to what you're attempting to do here? Is PHP providing some sort of web front-end, within which you believe that you'll be able to execute a Python script to scrape the web user's clipboard for images?

Comment: I have a web app to display photos, print, rotate etc. I detect if the device is touch enabled ie Ipad. To simulate a right mouse click the user does a long press on the image which I am able to trap and display a popup menu which allows the user to copy, print etc. The PHP script is called via $.ajax. The python script definitely runs prints but nothing is copied to the clipboard. If I run the same python script via the .bat file from the cmd level it works as expected as it prints "Done".

Answer (score 0):

Simple method to copy image from file to clipboard.
I am not sure this answers the Ops question but as I only just found the method described below I thought I would share it. I am on current up to date Windows 10. I am not aware of making any changes to make this work. I HAVE NOT tested this thoroughly - use AT YOUR OWN RISK!

- Right Click on image file in Windows Explorer (I did this on a jpg file)
- This brings up the Context Menu > select/hover over 'Send To'
- This brings up a "sub" context menu
- Near top of my sub context menu is "Clipboard (as content)" > select it
- This copied the image in the jpg file to my clipboard
- I copied clipboard to required app as Device Independent Bitmap  (Word)
- It worked fine.

I hope this is helpful to some of you. Passing it Forward. Best Wishes.